# Income tax return filing for F1 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, f1-visas

My father has not filed income tax returns for the past 3 years.

He will file the tax returns for 2014–2015 and 2015–2016 together in November 2016 and next for 2016- 2017 in April 2017. I hope it is fine for getting a student visa as the visa interview require the tax returns of last three years.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Welcome to TSE I feel this question is about a student visa, and as such it does not belong here but on the expats stack exchange. It is getting close votes already, likely it will be closed soon.